# Loading bitmap using Rx.observable

Tags: android, rx-android

I am using retrofit observable defer operator in my application, for loading bitmap into imageview.

Here my code is...

```java
public void getImages(final String bgBitmap, final ImageView bgImgView) {
    Observable.defer(new Func0<Observable<Bitmap>>() {
        @Override
        public Observable<Bitmap> call() {
            try {
                Bitmap bitmapLogo = HelpUtil.getBitmapFromBase64(bgBitmap);
                return Observable.just(HelpUtil.scaleBitmap(bitmapLogo));
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                return Observable.error(e);
            }
        }
    }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .filter(new Func1<Bitmap, Boolean>() {
        @Override
        public Boolean call(Bitmap bitmap) {
            return bitmap!=null;
        }
    })
    .subscribe(new Action1<Bitmap>() {
        @Override
        public void call(Bitmap bitmap) {
            bgImgView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
    }, new Action1<Throwable>() {
        @Override
        public void call(Throwable throwable) {

        }
    });
}
```

While loading the image in imageview its flickering wrong images and then load correct image.Any one can help me?.

Comment: Are you sure `bgImgView.setImageBitmap()` is called once? Place a log and track.

Comment: first you can replace the defer() call to fromCallable(), in this way yo just need the try block contents, the exception will be handled by the Observable that will created. 
anyway, nothing seems wrong with the Observable, probably you're calling the method twice somehow.

Comment: The image view is a Recyclerview. So while adding the image into adapter  i called the above method.

Comment: yosriz- Can you please give the code using fromCallale()?..